# WPF MainWindow doesn't close with .Close

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a small project where I have a login window and when the user is autheticated it will open a new window, that works but after the user logged in I want to close the Login window how ever, the main window doesn't close.

```
MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
mainWindow.Close();
Loader loader = new Loader();
loader.Show();
```

Comment: What's the context? Where are you calling the `Close` method?

Comment: please provide a minimal example that shows the behavior you describe. do you have any `Closing()` event handler maybe, that could cancel the close command?

Comment: @LukeDinkler I\m calling just after I\ve authenticated the user.

Comment: @dlatikay an example would just to make a new WPF application, close the main window and open another

Comment: Hmm... have you tried AmenoKenshi's solution? The MainWindow isn't designed to be closed unless reassigned.

Comment: consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636296/swapping-mainwindows-in-wpf?rq=1) possible duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing a new instance of a Window and close it immediateley afterwards.
It looks like your `mainWindow`is not the login window you want to close. If you want to close the current Main Window of you application, you can use:

```
App.Current.MainWindow.Close();
```

Make sure you also set a new Main Window. I assume you wanted to do something similar to this, also assuming "loader" is your new Window:

```
private void Login(){
    App.Current.MainWindow.Close();
    Loader loader = new Loader();
    App.Current.MainWindow = loader;
}
```